# Set 404 header status in htaccess for URLs with Query String in wordpress site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have a WordPress site in which there are a few URLs with Query strings. One sample page is:

```
https://www.example.com/2012/12/samsung-galaxy-music-duos-price-in.html?m=1

https://www.example.com/2012/12/samsung-galaxy-music-duos-price-in.html?m=0
```

So far I am able to set a 301 redirect to their main page using following code in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]
```

I want to set 404 status code for all of them and for that I changed 301 in this code to 404 but it did not work. Please suggest me the right code so that all such pages show 404 status code.

Comment: Rewriting to `/$1?` makes little sense in this scenario, I think. Try and use just a `-`. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule: _"A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path."_

Comment: Replace `/$1?` with just `-`.

Comment: Sorry Cbroe it did not work. In fact I tried this code also which has similar structure. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} . [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L] but it didnt work. best rgds still

Comment: How exactly did you verify, that it "didn't work"? Did you check what the actual HTTP response code is, when requesting these URLs?

Comment: After making the changes in htaccess I open the URLs to see if they redirect or show 404 page.

Comment: _"if they redirect or show 404 page"_ - what you currently have, won't achieve either of that. `[R=404]` _only_ sets the HTTP status code, nothing more. If you want to show your own 404 page instead - then you should rewrite the request to that, and set the 404 status code from _within_ your 404 page (which would have to be something dynamic like PHP then, a static HTML document can't set a status code.)

Comment: I just want to show http status code 404 only nothing more. thnx

Comment: "Show" doesn't really make sense, with regard to the HTTP status code. With `R=404`, your system should _respond_ with status code 404 already, please use your browser dev tools to verify that. And if you want _anything_ else, then you need to explain, what exactly.

Comment: By show I means it shall show 404 status when I check in header status checker tools which I am doing after I set htaccess code. You can check for sample URLs from my question. It shows 301 redirect and also the URL redirects to its parent page. Once I change code in htaccess set to 404 it doesnt show in checker and also the URL in browser also remains the same. thnx

Comment: _"Once I change code in htaccess set to 404 it doesnt show in checker"_ - so what does it show instead? _"and also the URL in browser also remains the same"_ - well of course it would - you can not redirect elsewhere, _and_ respond with status code 404, at the same time. (Redirecting _requires_ a 3xx status code, and there can be only _one_ per response.)

Comment: Bro thnx for your all inputs. I know how to check and what will be response in browser etc for 301 and 404. All I need code which can be used in htaccess file. plz let me know if you any other suggestion on same. thnx for all your inputs bro......

Comment: Try if using the `E` flag instead of `L` changes anything. And if not - then please show us _where_ you put this, within the already existing rewrite setup.

Comment: Tried with E but did not change header status code to 404RewriteEngine On.. the code is in top position. just 2nd only... the htaccess file for that part is below... 
# ensure www and https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.price4india.co.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.price4india.co.in/$1 [L,R=301]
# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [E,NC,R=404]

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work" exactly? Simply changing `R=301` to `R=404` _should_ have worked. HOWEVER, 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser, so you will _need_ to clear your browser (and possibly any intermediary) caches otherwise you will still see the earlier redirect (from cache). "`[R=404]` only sets the HTTP status code, nothing more." - **and** triggers Apache to serve the appropriate `ErrorDocument`. `L` or `END` (not `E`) makes no difference here (in fact, `L` is not even required when `R` is used with a non-3xx code). @CBroe

Comment: What is your `ErrorDocument 404` set to? Try setting to `ErrorDocument 404 default` (to use the Apache default 404 response).

Comment: MrWhite I just want 404 status code in header status checker tools. What page is shown is not a problem here. rgds

Comment: I'm still seeing a 301 redirect when I request that URL, and the response is from Cloudflare, ie. Cloudflare (your CDN) would appear to have _cached_ the response. You need to clear the caches in your CDN (an "intermediary" cache). The reason why I asked what `ErrorDocument 404` is set to is if this "rewrites" the request back to WordPress/PHP and WP overrides the HTTP status then you are not going to see a 404 HTTP status.

Comment: _Aside:_ What's wrong with having a 301? That would seem to be the preferred option anyway (instead of a 404).

Comment: Right now its set for 301 so its showing the same. I would prefer 404 as 301 is there for many months and still pages are coming again and again in google crawling list. Its never ending process. I want to get rid of all these pages asap.

Comment: yes there is Cludflare as intermediary but when I set 404 for other pages, it shows 404 status code in header status checker tools. so Cloudflare to me seems is not  creating any problem in this current problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code which I mentioned in my question worked though it gave some problems due cache and Cloudflare etc. I am sorry for misunderstanding and thnx again to CBroe and MrWhite for their inputs.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes, the code in your question "worked" in order to trigger a 301 redirect. However, your "question" is asking to change this to a 404 - which this does not do, so this does not answer your question? (Although, as mentioned in comments, a 301 is arguably the preferred response anyway in this scenario.)